# Question mark before identity reference ACL?

Tags: powershell

When using get-acl with Powershell sometimes I get a ? Before the identity reference.

For example domain/?dd

Does anyone know what the ? Refers to?

Comment: Does the identity have any special or region-specific characters?

Comment: None - it’s weird

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a forward-slash in an account name. Can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Sorry it is meanyt to be a backslash